# time.sleep, Flask and I/O wait

Tags: python, flask, wait, sleep

When using `time.sleep()`, will a Flask request be blocked?

One of my Flask endpoint launches a long processing subtask, and in some cases, instead of doing the work asynchronously, it is possible to wait for the completion of the task and return the result in the same request.

In this case, my Flask app starts the process, then waits for it to complete before returning the result. My issue here, is that while calling something like (simplified):

```
while True:
    if process_is_done():
        break

    time.sleep(1)
```

Will Flask will block that request until it is done, or will it allow for other requests to come in the meantime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that request is entirely blocked. `time.sleep()` does not inform anything of the sleep, it just 'idles' the CPU for the duration.

Flask is itself not asynchronous, it has no concept of putting a request handler on hold and giving other requests more time. A good WSGI server will use threads and or multiple worker processes to achieve concurrency, but this one request is blocked and taking up CPU time all the same.

Comment: Ok thank you! How can I do to allow Flask to handle incoming requests while waiting for this process to end?

Comment: @CyrilN.: you can't. Flask has no support for asynchronous handling of requests. Try to avoid blocking code, return early and have the client poll for status.

Comment: even if I put Flask on a Tornado wsgi server or eventlet?

Comment: @CyrilN.: **WSGI** is an asynchronous protocol. The request is blocked. `eventlet` **may** have patched `time.sleep()` to signal a yield, though.

Comment: @CyrilN.: see [eventlet.greenthread.sleep VS time.sleep in monkey-patched environment](//stackoverflow.com/a/25315314) for how to check if `time.sleep` is patched in that case.